# How to pass String as a Property in Groovy. Multi-level JSON

Tags: java, json, parsing, groovy, properties

I am really struggling to figure something out in a piece of code I'm working on to pass through a string to multi level JSON. I know that groovy will treat example ="multi.level "$example" as one single property and I have been trying to figure out how to split the string keep the delimiter and then add it to an if statement without any success. I have looked at other solutions but am unable to get them to work in my case... Any help would be appreciated.

**JSON:**

```
scriptOutput: [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "data": {
      "name": "fyre-discard-vm-1007"
    },
    "key": "ABCDE123"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "data": {
      "name": "fyre-discard-vm-1008"
    },
    "key": "ABCYRE123"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "data": {
      "name": "fyre-discard-vm-1009"
    },
    "key": "AZREDE123"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "data": {
      "name": "fyre-discard-vm-1010"
    },
    "key": "YTNER857"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "data": {
      "name": "fyre-discard-vm-1011"
    },
    "key": "YANT76563A"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "data": {
      "name": "fyre-discard-vm-1012"
    },
    "key": "DYAN31685"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "data": {
      "name": "fyre-discard-vm-1013"
    },
    "key": "SANF84923"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "data": {
      "name": "fyre-discard-vm-1014"
    },
    "key": "SADNS57985"
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "data": {
      "name": "fyre-discard-vm-1015"
    },
    "key": "DYUIK89OP"
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "data": {
      "name": "fyre-discard-vm-1016"
    },
    "key": "DHJMNNB6547"
  }
]
```

**CODE**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/groovy
import groovy.json.*


def proc7 = "curl  https://my-json-server.typicode.com/owainow/privateAPI/machines".execute().text

def slaveList = ["fyre-discard-vm-1007","fyre-discard-vm-1015","fyre-discard-vm-1016"]
def deleteMap=[:]
def jsonName = "data.name"

    println "scriptOutput: ${proc7}"
 def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(proc7)
  for (slave in slaveList)
{
  println(slave);
  if (json.find{it.data.name==slave}){ //This works as the properties are passed through as properties
  id = json.find{it.data.name==slave}.key
    deleteMap = deleteMap+[(slave):(id)]

// I would like to do something like this however I cannot figure out how to split my properties and pass them through in a way that works
/* if (json.find{it."$jsonName"==slave}){           SOMEHOW expand or split jsonName here
  id = json.find{it."$jsonName"==slave}.key
    deleteMap = deleteMap+[(slave):(id)] */

    println "Match"
    println (id)
    println deleteMap;
  }
  else{
    println"No"

  }

}
```

Cheers guys.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? what do you have in `jsonName` variable?

Comment: @daggett I need to stop posting questions so late in the evening. I have added jsonName, i'd like it to contain "data.name" in this instance although it will be somewhat dynamic. Might be one level deep maybe four depending on the run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why do you need this? why jsonName should be a string?

Asking this because to get `deleteMap` from `json` is quite simple groovy expression:

```
def deleteMap= json.findAll{ it.data.name in slaveList }.collectEntries{ [it.id, it.data.name]  }
```

however, if you still need it - groovy supports dynamic expression evaluation:

```
def jsonName = "ROOT.data.name"
def deleteMap= json.findAll{ Eval.me('ROOT', it, jsonName) in slaveList }.collectEntries{ [it.id, Eval.me('ROOT', it, jsonName)]  }
```

Comment: The reason its a string is because of jsonName being dynamic. jsonName could be "data.name" it could also be "hello.its.me" it depends on the users json data. The user decides what jsonName is.

Comment: So, i gave you a hint - Eval.me

Comment: Yes thank you I am working with the eval method to see if I can find a solution at the moment.

Comment: What does the ROOT do in this instance. I see that the code you gave above does work and I could, in theory, append ROOT. to the string within the script however I don't understand its use in the string or in the ('ROOT',it,jsonName)

Comment: `ROOT` it's the name for the variable `it` inside evaluation expression

Comment: Your solution works brilliantly the only issue that I run into is that I cannot format the deleteMap to use keys. I have tried adding Name and ID as keys however every time I try I get a syntax error and setting them before doesn't seem to work as they are gone after the command. Where would keys be placed in the above code? Thanks for all the help. The answer has now been marked as correct.

Comment: `collectEntries{ [it.id, Eval.me('ROOT', it, jsonName)]  }` builds map from any list.in the brackets you are defining a map key-value pair `[ KEY , VALUE ]`

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest to use the getAt() operator

```
it[jsonName]
```

but it turns out that you have a bug in your code, apparently:

```
id = json.find{it."${jsonName}"==slave}.key
```

should be

```
id = json.find{it.data."${jsonName}"==slave}.key
```

I would still probably use

```
id = json.find{it.data[jsonName]==slave}.key
```

Here's complete, corrected snippet:

```
import groovy.json.*


def proc7 = "curl  https://my-json-server.typicode.com/owainow/privateAPI/machines".execute().text

def slaveList = ["fyre-discard-vm-1007","fyre-discard-vm-1015","fyre-discard-vm-1016"]
def deleteMap=[:]

println "scriptOutput: ${proc7}"
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(proc7)
for (slave in slaveList)
{
    println(slave);
    if (json.find{it.data.name==slave}){ //This works as the properties are passed through as properties
        id = json.find{it.data.name==slave}.key
        deleteMap = deleteMap+[(slave):(id)]

// I would like to do something like this however I cannot figure out how to split my properties and pass them through in a way that works
/* if (json.find{it."$jsonName"==slave}){           SOMEHOW expand or split jsonName here
  id = json.find{it."$jsonName"==slave}.key
    deleteMap = deleteMap+[(slave):(id)] */

        def jsonName="name"

        id = json.find{it.data."${jsonName}"==slave}?.key
        if (id) {
            deleteMap = deleteMap+[(slave):(id)]

            println "Match"
            println (id)
            println deleteMap;
        }
    }
    else{
        println"No"

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help to begin with however I failed to mention that jsonName should = "data.name" as I know have hence not having data."$jsonName". I have added that now. The "$" method works passing one level of properties however if you add 2 that method treats the fullstop as part of one single property. The issue here is split or pass that string through as multi level properties.